# Click a button having object classid tags in selenium

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium

By using selenium(chrome driver) I am automating a web page. But in one case the webpage has a code as shown below(java applet). this has a button named "Sign". I want to click that button.

```
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5-windows-i586.cab#Version=5,0,0,5" width="130" height="25" name="Applet">
                    <param name="code" value="fjrff">
                    <param name="archive" value="">
                    <param name="mayscript" value="true">
                    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6.0-beta2">
                    <param name="scriptable" value="false">
                    <param name="fileNameField" value="up">
                    <param name="certificationChainField" value="ce">
                    <param name="signatureField" value="s">
                    <param name="tokenType" value="tokenType">
                    <param name="ButtonCaption" value="Sign">

                    <comment> <embed type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5"  <noembed></noembed> </comment>
```

I tried using

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("object[classid='clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93']")).Click()
```

But it didn't work. Is there any way I can click this button?

Is there a way to click on a element by simulating the click using coordinates in selenium?

Comment: The falls outside of Selenium's scope but I suspect the only way you can do this, natively in Selenium, perhaps tell Selenium (using the `Actions` mechanism) to find the  `object` element and move up/down/left/right by a certain amount of pixels.

Comment: @Arran What u mean by " natively in Selenium"? Cant be done using chrome driver?

Comment: ChromeDriver is not Selenium. ChromeDriver is an implementation of Selenium's protocol to allow you to "drive" Chrome, but the answer is no. By natively I mean by using Selenium code only. The answer is still no.